# Oracle: How do I indicate a truncated column result?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I truncate a query result and indicate that it has been truncated by appending "..."?

This example truncates results longer than 2 characters, but it has the unfortunate requirement of having *N* `when` clauses to truncate to *N* characters.

```
select 
  case length(x)
    when 1 then x
    when 2 then x
    else substr(x,1,2)||'...'
  end x
from (select 'ab' x from dual union select 'abc' from dual);

X
------
ab
ab...
```

Is there some way to add conditional logic such as `length(x) > 25` to the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you just want this?

```
select (case when length(x) <= 2 then x
            else substr(x, 1, 2) || '...'
        end) as x
```

. . .

That is, use the conditional form of the `case`, instead of the constant form.

Here is the complete code as expressed in the question.

```
select 
  case when length(x) <= 2 then x
  else substr(x, 1, 2) || '...'
  end x
from (select 'ab' x from dual union select 'abc' from dual);
X
------
ab
ab...
```

Comment: Brilliant, works perfectly.  I updated the answer to include the complete code from the question.